# Show the existence of a certain subgroup of F2

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-group-theory

This is a homework question: I need to find three subgroups of the free group with two generators, $F_2$, with certain properties. I have found the other two by constructing covering spaces of $S^1 \vee S^1$ and using fundamental groups; I don't think that this approach works here:

> Show that $F_2$ has an infinite index, free subgroup of rank two.

If anyone could nudge me in the right direction I'd be very grateful!

Comment: The number of sheets of a covering space is equal to the index. So you need a covering space with $F_2$ as the fundamental group and infinitely many sheets. You can combine the universal cover with a finitely-sheeted covering space to get what you want.

Comment: The universal cover in this case is just a sort of infinite grid of squares right? I don't see how to combine that with a finitely-sheeted covering space... Any cover with infinite sheets that I can come up with seems to have fundamental group with infinite rank

Comment: Check out page 58 of [this book](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html).

Comment: Ah yes excellent! I had forgotten about that one, it's been a while since I did covering spaces ...

Answer (score 1):

The free group $\mathbb{F}_2$ is the fundamental group of a bouquet of two circles $X:= \mathbb{S}^1 \vee \mathbb{S}^1$. Therefore, if $\hat{X}$ denotes the universal covering of $X$, then the derived subgroup $D := [\mathbb{F}_2,\mathbb{F}_2]$ is the fundamental group of $\hat{X}/D$; $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{X}/D$ are illustrated by figures 1 and 2 respectively.

[image]

If $T$ is a maximal subtree of $\hat{X}/D$, then $\{ \text{edges of} \ \hat{X}/D \ \text{not in} \ T\}$ is a free basis of $D$; explicitely, taking the maximal subtree $$T = (\{0\} \times \mathbb{R}) \cup \bigcup\limits_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R} \times \{i\},$$ we find

$$B=\{a^ib^ja^{-1}b^{-j}a^{1-i},a^{-i}b^jab^{-j}a^{i-1} \mid i>0,j \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash \{0\} \}$$

as a free basis of $D$. In particular, $D \simeq \mathbb{F}_{\infty}$. Finally, $\{ \langle x,y \rangle \mid x \neq y \in B\}$ gives you an infinite family of infinite-index subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2$.